# Replace characters, (alternative to SED), using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, notepad

I want to replace all `,` in a text File with `.` via Batch.

Actually I just need an alternative for this command

```
sed.exe "s/,/./g" $clearances.txt$ > $clearance_out.txt$
```

Problem is `sed.exe` is not installed on every PC I want to use this on so I plan to read and replace with the standard notepad editor from Windows.

Does anyone know how?

Example for the clearances.txt:

```
-12,7
-5,6
-7,6
-3,9
```

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with graphical user interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it the following way (using a batch file equivalent for your sed):

Name the file `replace_string.bat`

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "search=,"
    set "replace=."

    set "textFile=clearances.txt"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
```

First we want to make sure the delayed expansion is disabled (for the `for` magic to work).  Next set the variables to search for and in file.

Then in loop I use `type` to display contents of the file.  Then `^` is used to escape `& (run first command and then second)` and `>` (redirect).

Then save the loop variable `%%i` (the double `%%` is there due to the fact that we are in batch file) into `line` variable so we could use it.  Then we need to `enable delayedexpansion` so we could use the `!...!`.

The tricky part is `echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!`.

`echo(` normally prints empty line.  Here you need to have it for `line` variable expansion.  Without it you would get something like:

> 'line:' is not recognized as an internal or external command

So we where we have then (thanks to expansion) `12,7:,=.` which results into the final result `12.7`

Comment: omg it's so complicated. never in a million years i will be willing enough to learn batch i think haha. but it works, thank you very much!

Comment: @Mark I'm glad it works for you. it looks complicated at the beginning.  This is rather easy some really wild stuff is done by dbenham - https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham.

Comment: Let me recommend *not* to name the batch file `replace`, because there is also a command with that name...

Answer (score 3):

You could use `PowerShell` instead of `sed`.

From a batch file:

```dos
@PowerShell "(GC .\clearances.txt)|%%{$_ -Replace ',','.'}|SC .\clearances.txt"
```

At the Command prompt

```dos
PowerShell "(GC .\clearances.txt)|%{$_ -Replace ',','.'}|SC .\clearances.txt"
```

Comment: this is also good. actually it helped me even further for what i initially asked, because like this i can open other filestypes too. thank you

Comment: Is there any ability to use this to target the first character of a record in a file? I'm very novice with PowerShell and batch files.

Comment: @plankton, as your question is different from that which I answered, you'll need to [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Please note, if you do so, that we expect that you include a [mcve] of your code, _(written to actually perform the task you require of it)_, within your question, complete with an example of the input file content and your required output.

Comment: Will do. Should I tag you in the post? EDIT: You actually could just answer an existing question I have open - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855707/sybase-ase-isql-remove-blank-first-column-from-output-into-csv-file?noredirect=1#comment107673509_60855707